# How to disable same origin policy in the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, mobile-safari, same-origin-policy

I'm testing a web app on the iOS simulator through Xcode, but I think I'm hitting the same origin policy of the Mobile Safari. Is it possible to disable it?